# End caps for standing seam metal roof

Tags: waterproofing, roofing, metal-cutting, metal-roof

I've installed a standing seam metal roof as shown below:
[image]

Any ideas how I can approach the seam terminations shown above?

Here's a top view detail of one standing seam termination, showing where I've cut back the edges at an angle, in order to soften the seam profile when seen from the ground:
[image]

I've seen end caps such as this:

[image]
<sup>Image Source: [BestMaterials.com](https://www.bestmaterials.com/detail.aspx?ID=17944)</sup>

but perhaps there are better or less expensive solutions. Ideally I'd like a material that could match or complement the copper metal I've installed, rather than call attention to termination edges.

Comment: Did you have a company install that or did you? If a company installed it,  what do they say? If you installed it, maybe you could check with local contractors and ask their advice. I'm afraid that there might not be (but i could be wrong) many on here that have a lot of expertise with standing seam roofing, especially when it comes to finishing curved edges. It just doesn't seem like a lot of folks would take that on as a do-it-yourself project.

Comment: This very much seems like it's boiling down to a shopping question - "where do I find a similar product that's less expensive" - and that's off topic. Maybe "this product is too expensive, what's a DIY solution?" as the actual question would help.

Comment: Is the roof edge closest in the picture the highest edge? If so I would be more concerned about the rain water traveling on the underside of the roofing, getting to the sheathing and framing.

Comment: The correct way to do this, which I don't know if you still can, if to have the panels be 1" longer than the drip edge below and fold over the 1" overhand to hug the drip edge. Also, you're not supposed to have exposed fasteners. Finishing as I said would take care of your question. Hopefully you still have material left there to do that.